# Will a virtualenv continue working after a patchlevel upgrade to the underlying Python?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'd like to upgrade my system Python from 3.6.2 to 3.6.4 to get a bugfix.  Will this break my virtual environments that were built with 3.6.2?

Comment: I believe that in every virtualenv a new python executable is created, and as such your virtual environments will continue to run in 3.6.2, but I'm not sure enough about this to advise you to go forwards without more guidance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, as usual, is "it depends".

The `virtualenv` and `pipenv` tools copy the chosen python version to `env/bin/`. This means that point-releases will not be recieved by the virtualenv.

```
$ file env/bin/python3
env/bin/python3: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
```

The recommended `venv` (formerly `pyvenv`) tool however (on linux) creates a symbolic link to the version of python it is executed with (which can be though of as a "redirect" for file systems). This means that point-releases will be automatically received by the virtualenv if the original executable is replaced:

```
$ file env/bin/python3.6
env/bin/python3.6: symbolic link to /usr/bin/python3.6
```

This behavior is tunable, and `venv` can also upgrade versions in place, even if not using symlinks:

```
$ python3.6 -m venv -h
[...]
  --symlinks            Try to use symlinks rather than copies, when symlinks
                        are not the default for the platform.
  --copies              Try to use copies rather than symlinks, even when
                        symlinks are the default for the platform.
  --upgrade             Upgrade the environment directory to use this version
                        of Python, assuming Python has been upgraded in-place.
  [...]
```

As far as I can tell, the `virtualenv` tool has no such functionality, which is presumably one of the reasons it is suggested to use `venv` instead now.